# Validating dataframe columns data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Normal validations I am able to do using

```
 m1 = (df[some_column] == some_value )
 m2 = ( df[some_column].isin(some_list_of_values) )# This check whether the value of the column is one of the values in the list
 m3 = ( df[some_column].str.contains() # You can use it the same as str.contains())
 m4 = (df[some_column].str.isdigit()) # Same usage as str.isdigit(), check whether string is all digits, need to make sure column type is string in advance
```

Then to get the dataframe after all the above validations-

```
df = df[m1 & m2 & m3 & m4]
```

When I print `(df[some_column] == some_value )` I get

```
0 False
1 True
2 True
```

I want to validate something in a function using if else, like ,

```
if min_group_price is True , then both single_male single_female needs to be True
If min_group_price is False , then no check(Final result should be True)
```

My test data is something like ,

```
min_group_price single_male single_female 
0 1.0 2.0 3.0 
1 NaN NaN NaN 
2 1.0 2.0 NaN 
3 NaN 2.0 NaN 
4 0.0 NaN 4.0 
5 NaN NaN 2.0
```

In this as per the above logic, `index 0,1,3,5` should be True.
I dont want to iterrows . How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've just described some boolean logic which is easy to implement with pandas:

```
(~df['min_group_price'].notna()) | (
    df['single_male'].notna() & df['single_female'].notna())

0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5     True
dtype: bool
```

If 'min_group_price' is not null, then the result depends on 'single_male' and 'single_female' not being null, otherwise the result is `True`.

Comment: Hi.. it does solve my issue . But for a long validations like the one I have just updated in the question, how would we do that ?

Comment: @user1896796 you already have an answer to your original problem as stated. If you are unable to apply the answer to your own problem, please don't change the nature of the question... open a new one instead. Please at least produce a [mcve].

Comment: @ coldspeed . can you check help in this question.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53553873/validating-dataframe-column-data