# Validating dataframe column data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a below pseudocode which I need to write using pandas.

```
if group_min_size && group_max_size
      if group_min_size == 0 && group_max_size > 0
        if group_max_size >= 2
          errors.add(:group_min_size, "must be greater than or equal to 2 and less than or equal to group_max_size (#{group_max_size})")
        end

        if group_max_size < 2
          errors.add(:group_min_size, "must be greater than 2")
          errors.add(:group_max_size, "must be greater than 2")
        end
      end

      if group_min_size > 0 && group_max_size == 0
        if group_min_size >= 2
          errors.add(:group_max_size, "must be greater than or equal to #{group_min_size}")
        end

        if group_min_size < 2
          errors.add(:group_min_size, "must be greater than 2")
          errors.add(:group_max_size, "must be greater than 2")
        end
      end
    end
```

I tried to break in smaller parts and write something like below-

```
m8 = ((~df['group_min_size'].notna() & ~df['group_min_size'].notna()) | ((~df['group_min_size'] == 0) & (~df['group_max_size'] > 2)) | (df['group_max_size'] >= 2))
```

This is for

```
if group_min_size == 0 && group_max_size > 0
        if group_max_size >= 2
          errors.add(:group_min_size, "must be greater than or equal to 2 and less than or equal to group_max_size (#{group_max_size})")
        end
```

But is not quite working as expected.

Below is my test data -

```
   group_min_size  group_max_size
0             0.0             1.0
1            10.0            20.0
2             0.0             3.0
3             3.0             0.0
4             NaN             NaN
5             2.0             2.0
6             2.0             2.0
7             2.0             2.0
8             2.0             2.0
```

Based on the psudo code logic, the output should be:

```
False
True 
False
False
True
True
True
True
True
```

How do I write this logic in pandas?

Comment: @MohamedThasinah I have mentioned what I have tried. Breaking different ifs . and provided the code implementation as well

Comment: 4th would also be true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just answer your questions step by step. Begin by creating your booleans:

```
min_equal_0 = df['group_min_size'] == 0
min_above_0 = df['group_min_size'] > 0
min_above_equal_2 = df['group_min_size'] >= 2
min_below_2 = df['group_min_size'] < 2

max_equal_0 = df['group_max_size'] == 0
max_above_0 = df['group_max_size'] > 0
max_above_equal_2 = df['group_max_size'] >= 2
max_below_2 = df['group_max_size'] < 2
```

Now we can look at creating our masks according to the pseudo-code:

```
first_mask = ~(min_equal_0 & max_above_0 & (max_below_2 | max_above_equal_2))
second_mask = ~(max_equal_0 & min_above_0 & (min_below_2 | min_above_equal_2))
```

If we combine the two:

```
>> first_mask & second_mask

0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
8     True
dtype: bool
```

If you want to treat `NaN` as `False`, just add them:

```
min_is_not_null = df['group_min_size'].notnull()
max_is_not_null = df['group_max_size'].notnull()
>> min_is_not_null & max_is_not_null & first_mask & second_mask
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
7     True
8     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation . I was trying to fit all in one . That was really getting too complicated for me . I will start with this approach for any further validations.

Comment: np! writing pseudo code is good, but I think the fact that you were nesting the IF-statements made it confusing.